# Sliding doors animation in CSS like Twitter notification

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I'm trying to imitate **Twitter's notification** animation

---

[image]

---

This is what i came up with so far:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('#left').css('width', '400px');
  $('#right').css('width', '400px');  
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 50px;
}

.left {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 50px;
  background: #00AEEF;
}

.right {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  height: 50px;
  background: #00AEEF;
}

.banner {
  width: 0%;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="left" class="banner left"></div>
    <div id="right" class="banner right"></div>
  </div>
  <div style="margin: 10px;">
    <button>start animation</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

But using 2 different divs for left and right animation feels like a hack.

Is there a nicer built-in css animation of that type (to be used on a single div)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Sliding doors effect (only)

*(see below for a full-effect demo)*

You could animate the `background-position` of two `linear-gradients` placed in a single element (so you wouldn't even need to use two more empty elements for styling purpose) e.g.

```
div {
   background: 
       linear-gradient(to left, #00AEEF 50%, transparent 0),
       linear-gradient(to right, #00AEEF 50%, transparent 0);
   background-position: 50vw 0, -50vw 0;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   height: 50px;
   transition: background-position 1s;
}

:checked + div {
    background-position: 0 0, 0 0;
}
```

---

Just set a class via `js` to trigger the transition (for the sake of simplicity I've activated the effect with a `:checked` pseudoclass)

> [Codepen demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KzwrMM)

---

You could also obtain the same effect by the opposite animation: if you place a white gradient over a blue `background-color` you could animate just the `background-size` of the gradient like so

```
div {
   background: #00AEEF linear-gradient(to right, #fff, #fff);
    background-position: 50% 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    height: 50px;
    transition: background-size 1s;
}

:checked ~ div {  background-size: 0 100%; }
```

> [Codepen demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pyJvXq)

---

[Comparing the two approaches](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RaPPPZ?editors=1100) I personally prefer the last one (less code to type, one single gradient to be animated and it seems smoother. Furthermore, the second demo prevents an annoying rounding issue that sometimes happens in the first one, when repositioning the two gradients occurs, as you can see from the screenshot below)

[image]

---

## Full effect (with all the animations/transitions)

To recreate the full effect of this notification, markup and style should of course slightly change: starting from the last demo, I moved the main effect on the `<a>` element inside the wrapper and I inserted other effects, like the `@` pulsing with an animation and the final slide down after 5 seconds.

The right arrow is made by the unicode symbol `U+3009` and it is placed as the `content` of the `a::after` pseudoelement

Note: all properties are **unprefixed**. Add prefixes where necessary

> [Codepen Demo (Full effect)](http://codepen.io/fcalderan/pen/jqPrZM)

**Markup**

```
<div class="notification">
  <a href="#"><span>@</span>Miro mentioned you</a>
</div>
```

**CSS** *(embedding Lato font from google fonts)*

```
* {
  font         : 1rem "Lato", Arial;
  box-sizing   : border-box;
}

.notification {
   position     : relative;
   overflow     : hidden;
   font-weight  : 100;
   font-size    : 1.5rem;
}

.notification a {
    display     : block;
    padding     : 1em 3em 1em 2.25em;
    width       : 100%;
    font-size   : inherit;
    font-weight : inherit;
    color       : transparent; 
    background  : #00AEEF linear-gradient(to right, #fff, #fff);
    text-decoration : none;    
    background-position : 50% 0;
    background-repeat   : no-repeat;
    background-size     : 100% 100%;
}

/* The at-sign: I've also tried to use :first-letter but it
 * is unreliable when the first char is not a letter or a digit
 */
.notification a span { 
    position    : absolute; 
    line-height : 1;
    top         : 50%; 
    left        : 50%;
    color       : #fff; 
    font-weight : bold;
    transform   : translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
    transform-origin : 50% 50%;
}

/* The arrow */
.notification a:after {
   position  : absolute;
   content   : "\3009";
   right     : 1em;
   top       : 50%;
   transform : translateY(-50%);  
}


/* sliding doors effect, color change and final slide down
 * all with proper delays 
 */
:checked ~ .notification a {  
  transition: background-size .2s, color .33s 1s, transform 1s 5s;
  transform: translateY(100%);
  background-size: 0 100%; 
  color: #fff;
}

/* pulsing and moving the @-sign */
:checked ~ .notification a span {
  animation: pulse-at .66s ease-in-out .33s forwards;
}


@keyframes pulse-at {
    0%   { transform: scale(0)   translate(-50%, -50%); }
    20%  { transform: scale(1.1) translate(-50%, -50%); }
    25%  { transform: scale(1)   translate(-50%, -50%); }
    40%  { transform: scale(1)   translate(-50%, -50%); left: 50%; }
    100% { transform: scale(1)   translate(0, -50%);    left: 1em; }
}
```

---

**Final result**

[image]

Comment: Thanks again, so just to make sure i understand, what actually makes the animation two sided (and not just left to right) is the `background-position: 50% 0;` property?

Comment: @daniel, yes it's equivalent to `background-position: top center` so the white background is always centered. Just for fun I'm trying to recreate the full effect. I'll probably edit this post again with a complete example